# LR(1) parsing, problem with look ahead symbols

Tags: compilers, parsers

I understand the concept of LR(1) parsing and lookahead symbols. I have the solution to the exercise and it does not agree with my solution.

I'm trying to fill the LR(1) parsing table for the grammar below:

```
S->xAz 
S->BAx
A->Ay
A->e
B->yB
B->y
```

Ι don't have to extend the grammar since S does not appear in any right hand side of any rule.

```
First(A)=y,e
First(Ax)=x,y
First(B)=y
First(Ay)=y
```

Lookahead symbols in brackets.

So, 
I0 = Closure(S->.xAz($) , S->.BAx($) ) =

```
S->.xAz($)
S->.BAx($)
B->.yB(x,y)
B->.y(x,y)
```

When i try GOTO(0,x) i think that i should go to:

```
S->x.Az($)
A->.Ay(z)
A->. (z)
```

To find the lookahead symbol for **A->. & A->.Ay** i take **First(z)**. But the official book solution says the lookeahead is **(z,y)**. 
Where does that y comes from?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since $A\to .Ay$ is in the state constructed for $GOTO(0, x)$, $A\to .A(y)$ and $A\to .(y)$ are also in that state. These combine with the other items for the same productions, which have lookahead $z$.

Comment: Thank you so much!
If we combine the items that have the same LR(0) but different lookahead symbols, eg A->.Ay(z) & A->Ay(y) we also show that the grammar is LALR(1), correct?

Comment: @Nikos: No. The combination of items for LALR(1) grammars has to do with combining items from two different LR(1) states. Here, we're simply looking at a single LR(1) state, and the combination of lookahead sets is essentially a notational convenience (so that the same item doesn't appear twice in the same state).